# TSQL to return the dates of price changes from a price history

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a price history table that has these 4 fields

1. Id
2. Date
3. Product
4. Price

There is a record for ever day for every product. I'm trying to write a query to return a record for the starting price of each product along with a record for each time the price changed.

I tried grouping by price but obviously this breaks when a price changes than at a later date changes back as it will only return 1 record.

I've written this query to generate sample data that I am trying to work off

```
CREATE TABLE #PriceHistory
(
 [Id] INT IDENTITY,
 [Date] DATETIME ,
 [Product] NVARCHAR(30) ,
 [Price] MONEY 
)

INSERT INTO #PriceHistory([Date],[Product],[Price])
SELECT '20120101', 'Tesco', 1.99
UNION ALL
SELECT '20120102', 'Tesco', 1.97
UNION ALL
SELECT '20120103', 'Tesco', 1.97
UNION ALL
SELECT '20120105', 'Tesco', 1.99
UNION ALL
SELECT '20120104', 'Tesco', 1.99
UNION ALL
SELECT '20120106', 'Tesco', 1.99
UNION ALL
SELECT '20120101', 'BP', 1.99
UNION ALL
SELECT '20120102', 'BP', 1.01
UNION ALL
SELECT '20120103', 'BP', 1.99

SELECT * FROM #PriceHistory


DROP TABLE #PriceHistory
```

From that sample data the results I'm expecting should be

```
1 2012-01-01 Tesco 1.99
2 2012-01-02 Tesco 1.97
5 2012-01-04 Tesco 1.99
9 2012-02-11 BP 1.99
8 2012-02-20 BP 1.01
```

Any ideas on the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Shouldn't your results be 1, 2, 5, 7, 8, 9?

Comment: Sorry I should have said ordered by date. Although in most cases it's in date order anyway I just threw some out of order entries in the sample so we could cater for them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query starts with a price, and attempts to find the previous record for the same product with the same price... if there's no record for the same product at the same price, it returns the record:

```
SELECT ph.* 
FROM 
    #PriceHistory ph 
    LEFT JOIN #PriceHistory ph2 ON
        ph.Product = ph2.Product
        AND ph.Price = ph2.Price
        AND ph2.Date = (
            SELECT MAX(ph3.Date)
            FROM #PriceHistory ph3
            WHERE 
                ph3.Product = ph.Product
                AND ph3.Date < ph.Date
            )
WHERE ph2.ID IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Not very well tested, but try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT P1.* FROM #PriceHistory P1
JOIN #PriceHistory P2 ON P1.Date = P2.Date + 1 
OR P1.Date in (SELECT MIN(Date) From #PriceHistory P3) 
WHERE P1.Product = P2.Product AND P1.Price <> P2.Price
```

Adjacent dates; same products; different price

[EDIT to capture the "first" date]